# How to Login as a root in Fedora Core 11 GUI?

Tags: linux, login, fedora, root, fedora-11

I am working on a legacy system which requires me to login as a root in linux. I used to do it with my FC6.

I know sudo, su but It is very comfortable to stay as a root in GUI.

Is there any clean way to do this, If not Is there any patch ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simple Answer**

In Fedora 11 You cannot login from gui as a root.By Default only users are allowed to login from gui mode.

**Other Way**

If You want to login as a root from GUI in fedora 11 then you have to edit something like some files which are located to

> /etc/pam.d/

Open your Te rminal from `Applications -> System Tools -> Terminal`

Now Login as a root  from your terminal

**Step 1** :- [itsolutions@ask4itsolutions.com]$ su – root
Password:-

**Step 2**:- Now go to your /etc/pam.d/ directory.

[root@ask4itsolutions]# cd /etc/pam.d/

Then first take a backup of gdm file

> cp gdm gdm.bkp

( always take backup if anything goes wrong you can correct it by original file)

**Step** 3 :- Now Open gdm file in your favourite editor. I am using vi as my editor.

[root@ask4itsolutions pam.d]#  vi gdm

> Find and Comment or remove this line into your gdm file auth required pam_succeed_if.so user != root quiet

**Step 4** :- Save & Exit From that File. ( In Fedora10 Till step 4 is enought to Login as a root from GUI but for Fedora 11 you need one more file to edit otherwise you cannot Login as a root even though you edited gdm file).

**Step 5** :- Here is the additional file that you need to edit and that file name is gdm-password. Open gdm-password file in your favourite editor. I am using vi as my editor.

Then first take a backup of gdm-password file

> cp gdm-password gdm-password.bkp

( always take backup if anything goes wrong you can correct it by original file)

> [root@ask4itsolutions.com pam.d]#vi gdm-password

Find and Comment or remove this line into your gdm file auth required pam_succeed_if.so user != root quiet

**Step 6** :- Save & Exit from File. Now Press CTRL + ALT + BACKSPACE or Logout and Try to Login as a root user. Now you are able to Login as a root user from GUI in FEDORA 11.

If you are using Fedora 11’s Fingerprint Feature to Login as a root from GUI then you need to edit one more file also

**Step 7** :- Here is the additional file that you need to edit for fingerprint root login and that file name is gdm-fingerprint. Open gdm-fingerprint file in your favourite editor. I am using vi as my editor.

Then first take a backup of gdm-password file

> cp gdm-fingerprint gdm-fingerprint.bkp

( always take backup if anything goes wrong you can correct it by original file)

> [root@ask4itsolutions.com pam.d]#vi gdm-fingerprint

Find and Comment or remove this line into your gdm file auth required pam_succeed_if.so user != root quiet

**Step 6** :- Save & Exit from File. Now Press  <kbd>CTRL + ALT + BACKSPACE</kbd>  or Logout and Try to Login as a root user. Now you are able to Login as a root user from GUI in FEDORA 11

[source](http://blog.ask4itsolutions.com/2009/06/19/login-as-a-root-from-gui-fedora-11/)

***WARNING :- Its not at all good to login as root from GUI. It’ DANGEROUS. BUT if you want to know that how to login as a root from GUI then follow the steps instructions.***